# Checking an Array Element for Two Blank Space Characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

How would you be able to tell if an array element is made up of three words (i.e. if it has two blank space characters in it)? It might look something like `"abc def ghi"`. I am trying to search through an array for elements of this form and will remove this while others of the format `"jkl xyz"` or '"jkl"' would remain in the array.

Comment: Please, share your code - it will be easier to investigate where you have problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `search` function with following regex :

```
str.search(/\b(\w+ \w+ \w+)\b/g);
```

Read the detail in [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mK6oI2/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like:

```
/^[^\s]+\s[^\s]+\s[^\s]+$/.test("abc def def") // true
/^[^\s]+\s[^\s]+\s[^\s]+$/.test("abc def ") // false
```

It means:

```
^ Start of string
[^\s]+ 1 or more none space characters
\s a space character
[^\s]+ 1 or more none space characters
\s a space character
[^\s]+ 1 or more none space characters
\s a space character
$ End of string
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = ["abc def ghi","jkl xyz","gty slp","zxc vbn jkl"];
for (i=0;i<myArray.length;++i) {
  if (/\w+ \w+ \w+/.test(myArray[i])) {
    myArray.splice([i], 1);
  }
};
console.log(myArray);
```

---

Outputs:

```
["jkl xyz", "gty slp"]
```

---

<kbd>[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/yNBoKr)</kbd>

---

RegexExplanation:

```
\w+ \w+ \w+
-----------

Match a single character that is a “word character” (ASCII letter, digit, or underscore only) «\w+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “ ” literally « »
Match a single character that is a “word character” (ASCII letter, digit, or underscore only) «\w+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the character “ ” literally « »
Match a single character that is a “word character” (ASCII letter, digit, or underscore only) «\w+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
```